# How large are the generalized screen sizes in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I want to restrict my app to only tablets. The [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) from Android Docs is not much of a help! Should I use 'supports-screens' or  'compatible-screens' tag?

Should I enable  enable only xlargeScreens or both largeScreens, xlargeScreens in the manisfest file?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set a restriction in the market based on a specific screen size, but you can detect the screen size in your app. You could enable largeScreens to exclude most non-supported devices and then check on app startup if the user is using one of the smaller tablets that you don't want to support and then either notify them that they will have a diminished experience or aren't supported at all.

To get the device's reported screen size from within an Activity:

```
public double getScreenSizeInInches() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    float widthInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
    float heightInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
    return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInches, 2f) + Math.pow(heightInches, 2f));
}
```

One caveat is that some devices don't report correct values for xdpi and ydpi, but so far I've only seen that problem on some phones. All of the larger tablets seem to be at least close enough for this method to work.

Another option is to specifically exclude the devices that you don't wish to support from the Android Market interface. Obviously that only affects Android Market listings though. Other app stores may or may not provide that option.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If you want to include 7" tablet's then you need to enable largeScreens.  However, largeScreens also encompasses 5" handsets.  If you're planning to support only 3.2 and above, there is another option you can use to specify a minimum DPI size in the layout folders.  You can specify this in the manifest instead:

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

There is more information here under "Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2":  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank for your comment. But I cannot use the above attribute as I have to support 2.3+ versions. Is there another way to include only 7" and above tablets only?